# Allow user to specify endpoint

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I have created a desktop application in WPF that I wish to supply to clients as a .exe file.

Currently the application has a web service referenced to it where the web service would be sitting on the clients web server.

There is a high possibility that the URL of the web service could change depending on the clients therefore is it possible to add an option for the user to add the service reference themselves once they know the web service URL?

In the `app.config` is where the endpoint address is set, so if when the application fired up, it presented the user with a text box to enter the url, then on button click the application updates the service reference. Is this possible?

I have come across lots of different articles however was not sure if it was possible without have to recompile the code?

Comment: service client's ctor accepts the endpoint url as a parameter, it can be easily made customizable. At least, this is true for WCF services.

Comment: How would I implelement this solution?

Comment: I threw together a bit of code to demonstrate. I'm currently (ab)using this in a couple of projects, to be able to seamlessly deploy it in the development, staging, quality and production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a WCF service, if it's called `Service1` you can set its address like this:

```
Service1Client wcfServiceClient = new Service1Client();
wcfServiceClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("your uri here");
//now you will invoke the service in the address you defined
```

an ASMX service (still called `Service1` in this example for consistency) can be setup like this:

```
Service1 asmxService = new Service1();
asmxService.Url = "your uri here";
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Tested it on a dummy service that had an identical web method but different URL and it worked. Happy days.